# Make function more performant

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to complete a code challenge for fun. Here is the scenario.

Write `function scramble(str1,str2)` that returns `true` if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise returns `false`.

For example:
`str1` is `'rkqodlw'` and `str2` is `'world'` the output should return `true`.
`str1` is `'cedewaraaossoqqyt'` and `str2` is `'codewars'` should return `true`.
`str1` is `'katas'` and `str2` is `'steak'` should return `false`.

The function I wrote works, but takes to long to execute all possible tests. How can I make my function more performant? Thanks in advance.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    str2 = str2.replace(str1.charAt(i),'');
  }
  return str2.length == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "too long"?
 `scramble("piosdjfpasoidjfkoawmesfjatkjdsngfayksndglkjysngdlkjantokgsdannkogjmaoriewjgaeoirneorijgaeirgwoef","hello")` takes 0.06ms on my machine

Comment: `return str2.length == 0 ? true : false;` can be rewritten `return !str2.length;`. `for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++)` can be optimized in `for (var i = 0, j=str1.length ; i < j ; i++)` but apart from that...

Comment: After 61 tests have passed, it errors out due to 'It took longer than 12000ms to complete.'

Comment: `return !str2.length;` doesn't help.

Comment: @JoshSpears Are you using a JS testing framework of some sort?

Comment: Uh, I made [a test Pen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/QgGXmw), and 100 iterations give me 1.6ms, that's 0.016 ms per iteration.

Comment: The code challenge site has it's own testing system.

Comment: I suspect that your testing system might be taking longer than usual to run its own tests. This may not be your code after all.

Comment: @JeremyThille This is what the timeout error says 'Our servers are configured to only allow a certain amount of time for your code to execute. In rare cases the server may be taking on too much work and simply wasn't able to run your code effectiently enough. Most of the time though this issue is caused by inefficient algorithms. If you see this error multiple times you should try to optimize your code further.'

Comment: @JoshSpears Try to run the code outside of the testing server. If you are using Google Chrome, you can open the Network tab and monitor response time. Does it take more than 12 seconds to run your code?

Comment: Looks like their server is an old calculator, because this function executes 10 million times within the 12000ms limit on my normal PC.

Comment: Must be. I appreciate your help @JeremyThille.

Comment: `return !str2.length; doesn't help` --> Maybe, but it's so much more elegant :)

Comment: I agree haha @JeremyThille

Comment: It sounds like you are hitting a test whose inputs you haven't accounted for. Consider all possible inputs. There's also a short circuit at the top - `if str1 == str2 return true`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try writing the code now, but maybe a different approch could give interesting results.
Basically my idea is:

- Create an empty object
- Start looping through str2: get current letter, is the newly created
  object has a property called "current letter", increase the value of
  the property by one, or else add to that item the property "current
  letter" with value 1.
- Now for each property of the object, count if in str1 the letter has
  at least as many occurrences as the property's value

Here is the code:

```
let lettersCounter = new Object();
for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    if (typeof lettersCounter[str2[i]] !== 'undefined'){
        lettersCounter[str2[i]] ++;
    } else {
        lettersCounter[str2[i]] = 1;
    }
}
let props = Object.keys(lettersCounter);
for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i ++){
    let currLetter = props[i];
    if ((str1.split(currLetter).length) <= lettersCounter[currLetter] ){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

I think the really weak point here is str1.split - could probably be faster using a regex - but I hate writing regex, so I'm going to leave that to you :)

Oh, and as some wrote in the comments, you should do some initializations checks, like str1 === str2 and str2.length <= str1.length